# Higher resolution framebuffer modes?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, display, framebuffer

I have a raspberry pi plugged into a 3440x1440 monitor. Without setting any explicit `framebuffer_*` options in `/boot/config.txt`, it comes up at `1184x624`. The display is crisp and legible but individual pixels are huge.

I was hoping I could set the framebuffer to a higher resolution, but I'm not meeting with much success.  I've tried setting `framebuffer_width` and `framebuffer_height` to standard resolutions (like `1920x1080` or `1280x1024`),  as well as multiples of the current resolution (e.g. `2368x1248`).

They all "work" in that the display comes up, but in all cases the text is faded and distorted.

Is there any way to get the raspberry pi console to operate at better than `1184x624`?

**Edit**

This is for a Raspberry Pi 3B, running Raspbian Stretch.  Current kernel is 4.9.something.

Comment: Which model of raspberry pi? || What's the OS? || What's your exact problem? "*in all cases the text is faded and distorted*", it's all about the texts?

Comment: I've added the missing information; thanks for pointing that out. The exact problem is as described: "the console text (at resolutions other than the default) is faded and distorted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer was that I should be setting `hdmi_mode` and `hdmi_group`, rather than fiddling about with the `framebuffer_*` options. Setting...

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=58
```

...has things working quite nicely.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: The way Stack Exchange sites work is that you need to wait 24 hours after answering your own question in order to accept it. It hasn't been 24 hours yet.